# Заменить текстовый элемент json с помощью jsonb_set

Tags: json, postgresql

Есть json вида:

```
{"id": null , "answer": [{"code": "22", "information": "Заявка не одобрена, не указаны персональные данные клиента"}], "status": "error"}
```

необходимо заменить данные в поле information. До этого получалось изменять числовые данные с помощью jsonb_set, в данном json не получается это осуществить.

Пробовала запросом

```
UPDATE statement set metadata = jsonb_set (metadata, array['answer', 'information'], '"Заявка не одобрена, не соответствует дата рождения клиента"')where id_jon = 'as2536'
```

Вероятнее всего не правильно составляю запрос, подскажити как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "answer": [{

У вас массив объектов. Поэтому собственно `jsonb_set` вам даёт ошибку

```
ERROR:  path element at position 2 is not an integer: "information"
```

Это не имеет отношения к типу изменяемого элемента, это про указанный путь до этого элемента. На втором уровне вложенности у вас массив, у json массива ключ не может быть строкой, только числом. Если указать, что нас интересует нулевой элемент массива `array['answer', '0', 'information']` - то всё получится.

```
melkij=> select jsonb_set(
        '{"id": null , "answer": [{"code": "22", "information": "Заявка не одобрена, не указаны персональные данные клиента"}], "status": "error"}', 
        array['answer', '0', 'information'], '"За"');
                                    jsonb_set                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": null, "answer": [{"code": "22", "information": "За"}], "status": "error"}
```

Comment: А обязательно прописывать '{"id": null , "answer": [{"code": "22", "information": "Заявка не одобрена, не указаны персональные данные клиента"}], "status": "error"}'?
Если к примеру я хочу поменять у большого количества записей в бд сообщение, то указывать у каждого его метаданные будет слишком нагруженно. И можно ли как то изменить все таки через Update?

Comment: Можно, разумеется, пишите. Вы же уже сами (или нет?) написали запрос. Только один параметр функции указали неверно для структуры своего json.

Comment: UPDATE statement set metadata = jsonb_set (metadata, array['answer', '0','information'], '"Заявка не одобрена, не соответствует дата рождения клиента"') where id_jon = 'as2536'
Скрипт проходит, но данные не обновляются

Comment: Какой command tag возвращает база? `update число` - какое именно число?

Comment: возвращает - 0, поэтому данные не переписываются

Comment: Значит строки по такому where вовсе не существует. Что не имеет отношения к остальному jsonb_set

Comment: не очень поняла что вы имеет ввиду, запись с id которое я прописываю в условии существует, пропобавла и другие идешники указывать, везде аналогичная ситуация

Comment: update 0 означает что было затронуто 0 строк, т.е. ничего не найдено. Даже если ничего не было изменено в данных - всё равно был бы update 1. Следовательно строки подходящей под такой where не существует. Ну либо триггеры или rule в действии, тогда может быть всё что угодно.

Comment: спасибо вам большое, проблему разрешила, видимо что то было с бд, прогнала запрос на другой, он прошел.